# When i use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); page not working in angular

Tags: angularjs

**I want to remove # from URL** so i used $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); for remove url but when i use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); page not open and not working..

when i remove **$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);** page working properly and # showing in address bar.

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>route in angular</title>
<style>
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
header {
    background-color: #cb003e;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
     background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .3);
    /* width: 100px; */
    height: 100%;
    /* left: 0; */
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
}

.main {
    height: 500px;
    display: table;
}

footer {
    background-color: #cb003e;
    clear: both;
}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script> 

<base href="/" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">


<header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/project">Project</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 main">
            <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</main>

<footer class="text-center;">
    <h1 class="text-center">Footer</h1>
</footer>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/home", {
        templateUrl : "home.html"
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl : "about.html"
    })
    .when("/project", {
        templateUrl : "project.html"
    })
    .when("/contact", {
        templateUrl : "contact.html"
    })

    .when("/inder", {
        templateUrl : "contact.html"
    })

    .otherwise({
        templateUrl : "home.html"
    });

     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure. You may need to give your base url with your solution folder name i.e. <base href="/solutionFolder/">. If it didn't work then let me know what console error you are getting.

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS my all page are outside the folder so according to me i dont need give any folder name

Comment: Which browser are you running this app? It might  the browser not supporting `history` api which `html5Mode` rely on, if it's not supported, it'll fall back to hash prefixed urls.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro i used firefox and chrome both are not working

Comment: Does it support the history API? Like, http://caniuse.com/#search=history?

Comment: Have you configured the server to work with html5mode?  If by "not working" you mean you're getting 404 errors on all your routes, then the server is not set up correctly (it needs to redirect all paths to your app's location).  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Nevermind, I tested your example and it's working with `html5Mode` I believe your browser doesn't support the History API so that angularjs fall back to hash style urls. Also, as @DanielBeck has pointed out, when accessing an url directly you'll get a 404 Not Found because the server will process your request url, therefore you have to rewrite and point it to your index file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `.htaccess`? If not routing may not work properly.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```